# Executing a Aggregate function within a case without Group by

Tags: sql

I am trying to assign a specific code to a client based on the number of gifts that they have given in the past 6 months using a `CASE`.  I am unable to use `WITH` (screenshot) due to the limitations of the software that I am creating the query in.  It only allows for select functions.  I am unsure how to get a distinct count from another table (transaction data) and use that as parameters in the `CASE` I have currently built (based on my client information table).  Does anyone know of any workarounds for this?  I am unable to `GROUP BY clientID` at the end of my query because not all of my columns are aggregate, and I only need to `GROUP BY clientID` for this particular WHEN statement in the `CASE`.  I have looked into the OVER() clause, but I am needing my date range that I am evaluating to be dynamic (counting transactions over the last six months), and the amount of rows that I would be including is variable, as the transaction count month to month varies.  Also, the software that I am building this in does not recognize the `PARTITIONED BY` parameter of the over clause.

Any help would be great!

**EDIT:**
it is not letting me attach an image... -____- I have added the two sections of code that I am looking for assistance with!

```
WITH "6MonthGIftCount" (
    "ConstituentID"
    ,"GiftCount"
    )
AS (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "GiftView"."GiftID" FROM "GiftView" WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN("GiftView"."GiftDate", getdate()) <= 6 GROUP BY "GiftView"."ConstituentID")
    SELECT...CASE 
            WHEN "6MonthGiftCount"."GiftCount" >= 4
                THEN 'A010'
    )
```

Comment: Make it easy - and possible - to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: There is no screenshot in the question. And, regardless: please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, along with your current query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform your grouping/COUNT(1) in a subquery to obtain the total # of donations by ConstituentID, then JOIN this total into your main query that uses this new column to perform its CASE statement.

```sql
select 
    hist.*, 
    case when timesDonated > 5 then 'gracious donor'
         when timesDonated > 3 then 'repeated donor'    
         when timesDonated >= 1  then 'donor'
         else null end as donorCode
from gifthistory hist
left join ( /* your grouping subquery here, pretending to be a new table */
            select 
                personID, 
                count(1) as timesDonated
            from gifthistory i 
            WHERE abs(months_between(giftDate, sysdate)) <= 6
            group by personid ) grp on hist.personid = grp.personID
order by 1;
```

<sup>*Naturally, syntax changes will vary by DB; you didn't specify which it was based on, but you should be able to use this template with whichever you utilize. This works in both Oracle and SQL Server after tweaking the month calculation appropriately.</sup>